# Asynchronous post inside a loop not working

Tags: android, loops, asynchronous, post, retrofit2

I need to send multiple post requests with looping a list to my REST api. 
But after first succesful response second request is not sending to server. My code is as following;

```
for(int i = 0; i < sheets; i++){
    Call<Void> uploadCall = apiService.uploadSheetList(sheets.get(i));
    uploadCall.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response){
            Log.wtf(LOG, i+""));    
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t){
            Log.wtf(LOG, "Failed"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Log is below

```
0 --[1, 2, 3, ... never printed]
```

Comment: any exceptions ? which log appears `i` or `Failed` ?

Comment: if it's Asynchronous then there is a chance that you are making so many calls in a really short time making the API or the OS stop the calls. Try pausing every couple calls and see what happens

Comment: no exception @Yazan.. See edit for log.

Comment: sheets is greater than 1 right?

Comment: What is `sheets`?  Can you show us the declaration & assignment.